# Xserver error "(EE) module ABI major version(6) doesn't match the server's version(8)"

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04. Afterwards, xserver couldn't start. I have downloaded the latest nvidia drivers from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/340.32/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run&lang=us&type=geforcem) and rebooted. GRUB now has the following entries:

```
*Ubuntu
 Advanced options for Ubuntu
 Memory test (memtest86+)
 Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

When selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu" the following entries are displayed:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-34-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-54-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-54-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-47-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-47-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-46-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-46-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-44-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-44-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-42-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-42-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-41-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-41-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-40-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-40-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic (recovery mode)
```

After, installing the drivers, however, selecting any non recovery entry would lead to a black screen with a blinking cursor. After booting into recovery mode I have deleted all nvidia drivers by running:

```
sudo ./usr/bin/nvidia-installer --uninstall
```

Now I could again boot from any kernel without GUI enabled. I've tried starting xserver from the command line by running:

```
startx
```

An error related to ~/.XAuthority has occured. Running the command again as root threw the error:

```
Failed to insert nvidia. No such symbol
```

Next, I tried reinstalling xserver:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
```

The command was run successfully but I'm now getting the following errors when attempting to **startx**:

```
(EE) module ABI major version (6) doesn't match the server's version (8)
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Why does this occur?

**Edit #1:**

I have installed nvidia-current-updates:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

and ran **startx** again. The output was:

```
xauthL: timeout in locking authority file ~/.Xauthority
```

Afterwards, the screen kept flashing. I had to jump into terminal mode. The output is as follows:

```
waiting for X server to accept connections
```

and a screen of lines:

```
No protocol specified
```

**Edit #2:**

After removing the **.Xauthority** file and running **startx** the following error is shown:

```
(EE) module ABI major version (6) doesn't match the server's version (8)
xinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 2):

OK So you broke X, will will have to re install the system

You will need your live DVD/USB,or you have to make one.

Boot the live medium and choose install Ubuntu

If you see an option to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.04 (or someting like this UPGRADE is the important word) (at the top) use this to re install

If not, that's OK choose something else

Highlight your current Ubuntu installation and set its mount point to /

THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT There is a little box that says format on the drive make sure you UNTICK this box (eg format is disabled)

Then install, this will re install all the system files (including X) but will not change your /home folder of user details.

Reboot when it is finished

[Here is the documentation on this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation)

Comment: I've installed the nvidia-current-updates package and the result is show in the edited question. Strangely, now I cannot even drop into a terminal when I boot. Everytime I install an nvidia driver this happens: on start-up the logo flashes and then a black screen with a cursor in the top left corner is shown.

Comment: Did you do the next step ?

Comment: Please remove this driver first sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-curreny-updates

Comment: I have removed the .Xauthority file. Now I get (EE) module ABI version (6) doesn't match the server's version (8)... error. +1 btw

Comment: OK you broke X, you have two versions of files install in a big mess (they dont match your error says), but fear not I will update my answer with a fix for you soon

Comment: Thank you. This is quickly turning into a medium sized nightmare.

Comment: The new answer will fix your X server

Comment: I've tried the solution above. I do not have an upgrade option.

Comment: If you do not have the up[grade option you can, you can do this manually it is explained in the solution and the linked documentation, read from the line `If not, that's OK choose something else`

Comment: Before carrying it through I have a question: in /root I have numerous virtual drive images(.vdi files). Will the reinstallation remove them?

Comment: Yes I think so, just back them up first and then put them back after to be safe