# Restore Xorg core and config files ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, xorg, xserver

This question is a follow up on [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516039/xserver-error-ee-module-ani-major-version6-doesnt-match-the-servers-versi). I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and xserver broke during the process. I have tried reinstalling from the command line running the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get -y install x11-xserver-utils
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

None of the above fixed x. I've also tried "upgrading" from a live DVD. I could not find an upgrade option, however. Most options implied erasing current partitions and one a side-by-side installation with previous ones. Now I'm thinking about restoring the xorg files from the live installation on the previous(already upgraded 14.04) installation. How should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to do this is to simply to, yes, re-install.

You might also get away by `purge`ing the Xorg packages. To do this, you need to find out all of the installed X11 server packages and run:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove <X11 packages>
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Note that this may remove all configs for X11, GNOME, and potentially many other packages. It is ***VERY DANGEROUS***. I do not take responsibility if you break your computer.

You might also have luck deleting the X11 configs. I think most of them are housed in `/etc/X11`, but there may be more scattered around.

Comment: I'm looking for an option that does not involve these kinds of risks.

Comment: That is the problem with Linux, unfortunately. There are always risks to everything. Especially when you are playing with system configs.